# IIS 7.5 403 access denied errors when deploying ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

The scenario is pretty basic. I am trying to run my MVC 3 application on my EC2 cloud server. These are the steps I took:

1. Installed Web Role with default settings and added ASP.NET
2. Installed SQL Server Express
3. Installed MVC 3
4. Installed .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4.0
5. Installed all updates
6. Installed Web Deploy 2.0 and configured one click deploy
7. Created a new web site with its own application pool
8. Deployed my site

When I try to access it I get a 403 Access Denied Error. I can access static HTML pages so I assume it has something to do with user permissions and the Application pool. Before deploying it to the cloud I ran the exact same steps on a local virtual machine to test and everything worked just fine.

I did some research and I tried to select the site in IIS, click Authentication, edited Anonymous Authentication and changed the user to Application Pool Identity (although my local VM is running this under IUSR and it works) but still no luck.

I didn't do anything out of the ordinary so I am a bit at loss here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Anything in the event viewer? Assuming event viewer is available. Is your .NET framework set to version 4 on the server?

Comment: Do you mean the application pool set to version 4? Yes. If not, how would I check it? As to the event viewer I can see some messages in there. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Yep, when you create an application pool, it should have a dropdown list which allows you to select a .NET version.

Comment: Yes, I have it set to .NET 4 and integrated pipeline.

Comment: Do you know whether it's getting as far as reading a web.config? If it's getting that far, can you enable remote errors in a web.config?

Comment: It's not getting that far. Remote errors are enabled.

Comment: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` will do the trick for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please check whether this helps. It appears the order in which you install the components matters. [Link here](http://devopscloud.net/2011/03/25/mvc-3-ec2-and-windows-2008-r2/)

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I used to register .NET like that, but now I always use the Web Platform installer when installing MVC, I also choose the recommended IIS settings there... And it looks like it's still not OK. Running the aspnet_regiis.exe -i helped.